# Find inheritance chain of a dijit widget

Tags: dojo

Is there a dojo/dijit method to which i can pass a widget and get the inheritance hierarchy of that widget.

```
getInheritanceHierarchy(dijitWidgetInstance)
```

which will return the inheritance hierarchy in some format (json or array).

I checked the doc. Say for example, i want to find the inheritance hierarchy for dojox.grid.TreeGrid.
The doc says "Object » DataGrid » dojox.grid.TreeGrid", but when i click on the Datagrid link there, it goes to error page.

Comment: are you talking about a widget's scope or execution context?  You could try firebug...

Comment: @missingno: want to find this, because i want to know what are all the inherited methods and properties, and from which class they come from..

Comment: Isn't http://dojotoolkit.org/api/ enough?

Comment: @missingno:as mentioned in the question it says, the hierarchy but it does not says from which namespace the super class belong. Say for example it says DataGrid but no mention of the digit.DataGrid  or dojo.DataGrid

Comment: How would you do with multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

This prints the inheritance chain in reverse order:

```
dojo.forEach(MyClass._meta.bases,function(b) { 
    console.log(b.prototype.declaredClass); 
});
```

Replace `MyClass` with `instance.constructor` when using instances.

**NOTE:** This is likely to change or break and should **not** be used in production code! Useful only for debugging.